# generate a header row using python's csv.writer

Tags: python, csv

I have a bit of python code that produces a .csv file, however I don't know how to add column names, or a header row. Here is my code:

```
handle = open(sys.argv[1])
with open('protparams.csv', 'w') as fp: 
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"): 
            seq = str(record.seq)
            X = ProtParam.ProteinAnalysis(seq)
            data = [seq,X.get_amino_acids_percent(),X.aromaticity(),X.gravy(),X.isoelectric_point(),X.secondary_structure_fraction(),X.molecular_weight(),X.instability_index()]
            writer.writerow(data)
```

I have tried adding in something like:

```
writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',',[seq,aa_percentage,aromaticity,gravy,isoelectric_point,secondary_structure_fraction,molecular_weight,instability_index])
```

but this obviously doesn't work

anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the headers before the loop:

```
handle = open(sys.argv[1])
with open('protparams.csv', 'w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['heading1','heading2','heading3'])
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"):
            seq = str(record.seq)
            X = ProtParam.ProteinAnalysis(seq)
            data = [seq,X.get_amino_acids_percent(),X.aromaticity(),X.gravy(),X.isoelectric_point(),X.secondary_structure_fraction(),X.molecular_weight(),X.instability_index()]
            writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: ah so simple, how I didn't see it.